# How to yii getPost and analyse post Parameters?

Tags: yii

I have many clients send post to the server.
That is post url:

```
localhost/checkpost.php
parms:
id = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
<contents><name>user</name><detail>test<detail></contents>
```

I want check id and name with my database and save detail to my database.How can i do that?
Help me i am newbie in Yii?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the get/post data with the [CHttpRequest class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest). This is accessible as

```
$id = Yii::app()->request->getParam('id');    // Either GET or POST
$id = Yii::app()->request->getPost('id');     // POST only
$id = Yii::app()->request->getQuery('id');    // GET only
```

If you want to work with the database, the easiest is to implement an [CActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar)-derived class and use that for interfacing with the database.

Comment: I think my question was wrong. I will edit it. Not one client, many client and 1 id per a client. I think i must have a protocol to getpost.

Comment: My answer remains the same after your edit, what the getParam/Post returns is what has been posted to your checkpost.php. I'll add a bit more info about the database part.